# Error while osgi-fying existing webservice war

Tags: java, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I am deploying my existing webservice war(its working on tomcat) on jboss fuse. I changed my manifest.mf like below

`Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: HelloCxfWS
Bundle-SymbolicName: HelloCxfWS
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-ClassPath: WEB-INF/classes/
Required-Bundle: org.apache.cxf.cxf-bundle
Import-Package: javax.jws,javax.wsdl,javax.xml.bind,javax.xml.bind.annotation,javax.xml.namespace,
 javax.xml.ws,META-INF.cxf,META-INF.cxf.osgi,
 org.apache.cxf.bus, org.apache.cxf.bus.spring,org.apache.cxf.bus.resource,
 org.apache.cxf.configuration.spring,org.apache.cxf.resource,org.apache.cxf.jaxws, 
 org.apache.servicemix.cxf.transport.http_cxf,org.springframework.beans.factory.config,
 org.apache.servicemix.cxf.transport.http_osgi
Private-Package: com.irk.test.ws.*
DynamicImport-Package: *`

But i am getting following error in logs

`13:24:00,757 | WARN  | edhat-024/deploy | fileinstall                      | 7 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.3.11.redhat-60024 | Error while starting bundle: file:/E:/jboss-fuse-6.0.0.redhat-024/deploy/HelloCxfWS.war
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle HelloCxfWS [292]: Unable to resolve 292.0: missing requirement [292.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.servicemix.cxf.transport.http_cxf)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4155)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.redhat-60024.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2055)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.redhat-60024.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:955)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.redhat-60024.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1247)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.3.11.redhat-60024]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1219)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.3.11.redhat-60024]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startAllBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1208)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.3.11.redhat-60024]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:503)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.3.11.redhat-60024]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:291)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.3.11.redhat-60024]`

Please help in this regard

Regards,

Comment: [292]: Unable to resolve 292.0: missing requirement [292.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.servicemix.cxf.transport.http_cxf). You do not have the package in any bundle or that bundle did not start.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

> Require-Bundle:

instead of

> Required-Bundle:

Is the bundle `org.apache.cxf.cxf-bundle` available?

Comment: how i can verify this? in jboss fuse it should be available by default? plz correct me if my understanding is wrong

Comment: I done changes and now getting following error    Unable to resolve 310.0: missing requirement [310.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet)